# mod_rewrite getting 500 internal error

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

Im using this code to redirect other domains to my main domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} redirect1\.cl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.cl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.maindomain.cl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.cl
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.maindomain.cl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But im trying to redirect another domain so I add another rule like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} redirect2\.cl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.cl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So the rules looks like this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} redirect1\.cl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.cl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} redirect2\.cl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.cl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.maindomain.cl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.cl
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.maindomain.cl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When adding redirect2 domain I get server internal error. Ive tried different combinations but cant get it to work.

Comment: Rule 1 when you get an internal server error: Check your apache error log. Google if you don't know where this log is located. Please then edit your question and edit in what the error that is logged is.

Comment: Im gettin redirection loop

Comment: What url are you testing it with?